# Market data: what is "EANS-News"?

Tags: market-data, news

There are a number of market news providers like Reuters, Bloomberg, EQS, etc.
While searching for news regarding certain German or Austrian securities I encountered a number of news articles which begin with phrase "EANS-News". This [news article](https://www.finanznachrichten.de/nachrichten-2019-09/47651423-eans-news-atrium-european-real-estate-limited-update-to-recommended-cash-acquisition-by-scheme-of-arrangement-and-go-shop-process-015.htm) could serve as an example.
Does anyone know what EANS might stand for? Is it yet another market news provider?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beginning of the article in your link says:

```
=-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Corporate news transmitted by euro adhoc with the aim of a Europe-wide 
distribution. The issuer is responsible for the content of this announcement.
=-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

EANS stands for "Euro Adhoc News Service". [Euro Adhoc](https://www.euroadhoc.at) is an investor relations dissemination service based in Austria. Public companies use Euro Adhoc to fulfill their disclosure requirements and distribute press releases to the media. It has distribution channels to German-language media in Austria, Germany and Switzerland, as well as to global financial news services (Bloomberg, Reuters, Dow Jones, etc.).